# Changing display text based on scheduled GMT

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

Normally I have done a bit of work to get to where I need to ask for help, but I'm totally stumped on this one.

Using plain ol JavaScript, I need to change the text of an element based on whether or not it falls during any of the following hour/day combinations:

```
M-F 5:00 AM-9:00 PM Pacific Time
Sa-Su 5:00 AM-5:30 PM Pacific Time
```

I know how to do this if the people viewing the site are in the same time zone, but I am lost on what to do to ensure everyone see's the right thing regardless of their local timezone.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pacific Standard Time is UTC-0800, however everywhere that uses PST also observes daylight saving so just converting to PST may not be sufficient.

Anyway, as [pretzelhammer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452087/2766908) you can convert the PST times to UTC to create suitable Date objects, then compare with those. Note that 21:00 PST is 05:00 UTC the next day, but that's not really a problem. You can set the start time as 13:00 UTC then just add 16 hours Monday to Friday, or 12.5 hours on Saturday and Sunday.

To get the right start date, if it's before 08:00 UTC, change the UTC date to the previous day and the time to 05:00. Then depending on whether it's a week day or week end, the finish is set by adding the open duration.

```js
// M-F   05:00 - 21:00 PST -> 13:00 - 05:00 UTC
// Sa-Su 05:00 - 17:30 PST -> 13:00 - 01:30 UTC

function getRange(date) {
  // Start is 1300 UTC every day
  var start = new Date(date);
  // If before 0800 UTC, set to previous day
  if (start.getUTCHours() < 8) {
    start.setDate(start.getDate() - 1);
  }
  start.setUTCHours(13,0,0,0);
  // Set end to +16 or +12.5 hours if weekend
  var end = new Date(start);

  if (end.getDay() % 6) {
    end.setHours(end.getHours() + 16);
  } else {
    end.setHours(end.getHours() + 12, 30);
  }
  
  return [start, end];
}

function isInRange(date) {
  date = date || new Date();
  var range = getRange(date);
  return date >= range[0] && date <= range[1];
}

// Helper to get current time PST (UTC-0800)
function getPSTTime(date) {
  date = date || new Date();
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  var d = new Date(date);
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours()-8);
  
  return 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' ' )[d.getUTCDay()] + ' ' + z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + z(d.getUTCMinutes());
}

// Is the current time in range?
var d = new Date();
console.log('PST Time: ' + getPSTTime());
console.log('Is it in range? ' + (isInRange(d)? 'yes':'no'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to convert your hours into UTC time and then use JS Date's UTC functions. UTC is 7 hours ahead of Pacific Time (right now) so your UTC hours would be:

```
M-F 12:00 PM - 4:00 AM UTC
Sa-Su 12:00 PM - 12:30 AM UTC
```

Then knowing that you can do:

```js
function isItWorkingHours(date = null) {
  date = date ? date : new Date();
  const utcDay = date.getUTCDay();
  const utcHour = date.getUTCHours();
  const utcMinute = date.getUTCMinutes();
  
  if (utcHour >= 12) { // any day after noon
    return true;
  } else if (
    utcHour === 0 && // between 12 AM & 1 AM
    utcMinute <= 30 && // before 12:30 AM
    utcDay <= 1 // on sunday or monday
    ) {
    return true;
  } else if (
    utcHour <= 4 && // before 4AM
    utcDay >= 2 && // on or after Tuesday
    utcDay <= 7 // on or before Saturday
    ) {
    return true;  
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isItWorkingHours());
```

Granted, that is a bit confusing, and you will have to update it a little since Pacific Time goes in and out of Daylight Savings while UTC ignores it. If you're willing to pull in a 3rd party dependency you should definitely look into using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: It's much simpler: just set the time and [*Compare two dates with JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript). ;-)